# Django Gmail Api- Download Feature

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, gmail-api

I need help in one of my project, I am creating a django application which extracts mails from Gmail using Gmail API for Python & avail extracted mails to the user in JSON format which they can download.
but the problem lies in fetching session, it takes too much time to fetch mails(for 100 mails 72 seconds, its too much). so as a user it will irritate me. 
Please give suggestion if anything can be done to minimise fetch time.

As an alternate solution, I have thought to add one more feature i.e. "Mail me When my Download ready..!".
In this received mails from Gmail server in JSON format will be stored in our local database and a mail will be sent to the user with link to download that JSON file.

As I'm new to Django, I don't know how to implement it. Your valuable suggestions and help will be really helpful for me.
Please help.

Comment: Have you considered caching the data somewhere, using maybe a background task (like Celery), so on future requests it will be faster.

Comment: Thank you Kevin! Finally someone responded. And yeah I am working on it.